# Extracting vector/raster data for CSV data points

Tags: qgis, qgis-plugins, spatial-statistics

I am using QGIS and I have a CSV file of lat and long coordinates which represents presence points of a species in the USA. I also have vector (the state extents/names) as well as raster information (NDVI, bioclim, elevation, etc.). I would like to be able to extract data from both the vector and rasters which is associated with each coordinate. For example, so I can say X amount of coordinates were in Kentucky, and X points were at an elevation greater than 500 m.

At this point I would just like to ask if anybody can please suggest any QGIS tools or plugins that are able to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can either do a [spatial join](https://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/spatialJoin/) or use the [Point Sampling Tool](https://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/pointsamplingtool/)